# I wanted to bring the id opposite the searched text with the query I wrote. I got "NullPointerException" error when trying to get an id

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing

When I took the text typed in the search bar and clicked the search button, I tried to bring up the id opposite this search text in the database. But I got an error. The query is working correctly.I'm trying to get a value of 4 like in this photo. I showed the error I got, that my query is running in the database and what happens when the search button is clicked.

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            String searchKey = txtSearch.getText().toLowerCase();
            
            Connection connection;
            DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper();
            connection = dbHelper.getConnection();
            ResultSet resultSet;
            
            
            PreparedStatement statement =null;
            String sql ="select * from cities where city_name = '"+searchKey+"'";
            System.out.println(sql);
            resultSet= statement.executeQuery(sql);
            
            int id = resultSet.getInt("city_id");
            System.out.println(id);
           
            
            model = (DefaultTableModel)tblcinema.getModel();
            model.setRowCount(0);
            
            ArrayList <Sinemalar> sinemalar = getSinemalar(id);
            for (Sinemalar sinema : sinemalar){
                Object [] row={sinema.getCinema_id(),sinema.getCinema_name(),sinema.getCinema_adress()};
                model.addRow(row);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

[image: database]

```
run:
select * from cities where city_name = 'denizli'
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Uye.Anasayfa.jButton2ActionPerformed(Anasayfa.java:308)
    at Uye.Anasayfa$3.actionPerformed(Anasayfa.java:123)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2764)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)
```

Comment: What code is on line 308?

Comment: Sorry..  " resultSet= statement.executeQuery(sql); "

Comment: So it's pretty obvious 2 lines up you declare `PreparedStatement statement =null;` and you then try to use `statement` which is still null on line 308... obviously it's still null you haven't declared it as anything else

Comment: Saying things like "the sql is executing correctly" limits your thinking. If you post a stacktrace, identify the line where the error is, esp. null pointers. Just suggestions for future questions, although in fact null pointer questions seem to be frowned on around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Furthering my comment:

> So it's pretty obvious 2 lines up you declare PreparedStatement statement =null; and you then try to use statement which is still null on line 308... obviously it's still null you haven't declared it as anything else

You should be doing (notice I declare the `PreparedStatement` with the `query` via the `conenction` and then call `executeQuery()` with no parameters):

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
//...
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

[Here](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-select-like/) is a tutorial if you need.

It would also help to learn [how to debug java code in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684892/debugging-java-in-netbeans) or in [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php#:%7E:text=A%20Java%20program%20can%20be,to%20start%20the%20Java%20application.) and also what a [NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/1133011) means

Comment: you are right. I really do not know much about this things. I had to start from the middle of the subject because of the project. yes statement is still empty. but when I do as you said, how do I say getInt and get an id? we only do it with resultSet.

Comment: Please look at the tutorial I linked in my statement *Here is a tutorial if you need.* by clicking on the word  *Here*. It shows you exactly what you need.

Comment: I've also updated my code snippet to correct your code further

Comment: now I see it and the problem is solved. thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad to help 